# WooCommerce not including template single-product.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing my WooCommerce theme (hereinafter referred to as WC).
WC does not see the single-product.php template, and load index.php instead. At the same time, on the catalog page, the custom archive-products.php is loaded.

Guys, neither custom nor original single-product.php is loaded. Tell me, please, what to do?

I did:

1. Create woocommerce directory in theme folder
2. Inside mytheme/woocommerce I placed custom archive-products.php and single-product.php
3. I added WC support in functions.php. I checked the support in the site admin panel - everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory again and make sure the file name is correct. it must be `archive-product.php` Not `archive-products.php`.

It's better if you copy the plugin template file in your theme directory then modify it.

Example: To override the archive-product.php, copy: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` to `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`

Reference: https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#how-to-edit-files

Comment: Sorry, `archive-products.php` is missprint. I gave a correct name to this file, really (`archive-product.php`). All pathes to override files are correct too. 
What else could be the problem?

Comment: Woocommerce didn't see `single-product.php`, neither `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php` nor `wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/single-product.php`

Comment: try to update plugin and switch theme to default WP theme. Or try disabling other plugins one by one.